# inconsolata bold on old ubuntu/precise/TexLive

Tags: fonts, packages, installing

I'm trying to use inconsolata bold in a pdflatex document.
My system is `ubuntu 12.04/precise` and here's part of the TeX log with `\listfiles`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(...)
inconsolata.sty    2009/06/07 Inconsolata
(...)
```

After `\usepackage{inconsolata}`, `\texttt{some regular \textbf{and bold} text}` uses the inconsolata font but the bold is the same as the regular one - no difference.

Since http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/ suggests that a more recent version of the package does have a bold font, how would I install this - on a computer where I *don't have root access*?

N.B. package `zi4` doesn't exist on my system either and I can't find it in the package manager, so looks like it'll have to be a manual install. I've already got a `~/texmf/` directory for some other packages that are out of date on this system.

Comment: The easiest way is to download `install/fonts/inconsolata.tds.zip` from CTAN, put it in your texmf directory, change to that directory and unzip it. Then, if that directory has a `ls-R` file, run `mktexlsr` to update it. Finally, run `updmap --enable Map=zi4.map`. The `zi4` package comes along with that.

Comment: I'm still missing something: for the document

    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{zi4}
    \begin{document}
    \texttt{some regular \textbf{and bold} text}
    \end{document}

I get:

    ! Font OT1/zi4/m/n/10=ot1-zi4r-0 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not 
found.

I did mktexlsr and updmap and the files are in `~/texmf/tex/latex/inconsolata/`, it finds the `zi4.sty` file, what am I still missing?

(somehow my markdown's not working either)

Comment: Do you have the following exact path and file below your `~/texmf/` directory: `fonts/tfm/public/inconsolata/ot1-zi4r-0.tfm`? What happens when you run `kpsewhich ot1-zi4r-0.tfm`?. When you ran `mktexlsr` did you see your `~/texmf/` directory mentioned in the screen output? Try running `kpsewhich --expand-var=$TEXMF` and see if `~/texmf` is listed.